# StripeInvalidRequestError: Invalid integer: NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

Problem here:

```
H:\Project\b612-used-products-resale-server-side\node_modules\stripe\lib\Error.js:38
        return new StripeInvalidRequestError(rawStripeError);
               ^

StripeInvalidRequestError: Invalid integer: NaN
    at StripeError.generate (H:\Project\b612-used-products-resale-server-side\node_modules\stripe\lib\Error.js:38:16)
    at res.toJSON.then.StripeAPIError.message (H:\Project\b612-used-products-resale-server-side\node_modules\stripe\lib\StripeResource.js:190:35)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  raw: {
    code: 'parameter_invalid_integer',
    doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer',
    message: 'Invalid integer: NaN',
    param: 'amount',
    request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_qrB9pkb0RSnXLE?t=1674054016',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Wed, 18 Jan 2023 15:00:16 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '337',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
      'access-control-max-age': '300',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      'idempotency-key': 'de806504-9d20-4c22-876a-51e9f513f262',
      'original-request': 'req_qrB9pkb0RSnXLE',
      'request-id': 'req_qrB9pkb0RSnXLE',
      'stripe-version': '2022-11-15',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    statusCode: 400,
    requestId: 'req_qrB9pkb0RSnXLE'
  },
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: 'parameter_invalid_integer',
  doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer',
  param: 'amount',
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Wed, 18 Jan 2023 15:00:16 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '337',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'idempotency-key': 'de806504-9d20-4c22-876a-51e9f513f262',
    'original-request': 'req_qrB9pkb0RSnXLE',
    'request-id': 'req_qrB9pkb0RSnXLE',
    'stripe-version': '2022-11-15',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  requestId: 'req_qrB9pkb0RSnXLE',
  statusCode: 400,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined
}

Node.js v18.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Server code:

```js
app.post('/create-payment-intent', async (req, res) => {
  const booking = req.body;


  const price = booking.price;
  const amount = price * 100;

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    currency: 'usd',
    amount: amount,
    "payment_method_types": [
      "card"
    ],
  });

  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  })
})
```

Check Out form:

```js
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const CheckoutForm = ({booking}) => {
   
    const [cardError, setCardError] = useState('');

    //const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');
    //const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false);
   // const [transactionId, setTransactionId] = useState('');
     const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

  

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const { price } = booking;

    useEffect(() => {
        // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/create-payment-intent", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                authorization: `bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ price }),
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
    }, [price]);



    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!stripe || !elements) {
            return
        }

        const card = elements.getElement(CardElement);
        if (card === null) {
            return;
        }
        const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card
        });

        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            setCardError(error.message);
        }
        else {
            setCardError('');
        }
      //  setSuccess('');
       // setProcessing(true);

    //    const { paymentIntent, error: confirmError } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
    //     clientSecret,
    //     {
    //         payment_method: {
    //             card: card,
    //             billing_details: {
    //                 name: productname,
    //                 email: email
    //             },
    //         },
    //     },
    //);

    // if (confirmError) {
    //     setCardError(confirmError.message);
    //     return;
    // }

    // console.log('paymentIntent', paymentIntent )

    
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <CardElement
                options={{
                    style: {
                        base: {
                            fontSize: '16px',
                            color: '#424770',
                            '::placeholder': {
                                color: '#aab7c4',
                            },
                        },
                        invalid: {
                            color: '#9e2146',
                        },
                    },
                }}
            />
            <button
                className='btn btn-sm mt-4 btn-primary'
                type="submit"
                disabled={!stripe || !clientSecret}>
                Pay
            </button>
        </form>
         <p className="text-red-500">{cardError}</p>
        
    </>
    );
};

export default CheckoutForm;
```

I want to remove stripe request *Invalid integer: NaN*

Comment: The error seems pretty clear? You're passing a `NaN` value, so step one is: do some debugging to see what values you're actually passing to Stripe. That's something only you can do, we can't do that for you. And in the process of that investigation, you're almost certainly going to find the problem.